# Is it true that it's unsafe to put an e-collar on a cat? Are there any alternatives to it that cats would find more comfortable?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, parasites, allergies, scratching

My dad is a veterinarian, and he refuses to put an e-collar on our cat, who's scratching her throat and ears (both front and back) so badly she's reached flesh. We tried putting ointment on her but she hates it and licks it all off in minutes.

Please help me, I respect his word as a vet but I don't want my cat to die because of  *allergies*.

Comment: Have you figured out WHY your cat is scratching yet? You mentioned allergies, what is she allergic against? Something seems to be irritating her skin, you need to tackle that, not punish her for trying to relief the irritation!

Answer (score 2):

### Step # 1

If your cats allergies are that severe we really need to figure out whats causing the problem and to soothe the inflammation in the meantime. This will have to be done with your DVM.

### Step  # 2

We don't put plastic e-collars on our cats instead we have a softer solution - we use EZ Soft E-collars, they are made with fabric so the cat doesn't feel the impact of banging into walls. It is **not** dangerous to wear these.

[image]

I would also trim your cats nails to reduce the damage she does to herself, keep her indoors as well to reduce risk of infection from open wounds and to keep her safe (less defense).

**Note: E-collars are for temporary protection and are not to be substituted for treatment.**